# Why is the almighty force called Phoenix Force?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-dark-phoenix

In the movie *X-Men: Dark Phoenix* the almighty force is known as Phoenix force, why is it named as such? The name of the force is also the inspiration for the name of the movie. What are its similarities with Phoenix (bird)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Phoenix of legend is a bird that is born from the ashes of either itself or its parent. It has long been associated with resurrection and rebirth.

The Phoenix Force is so named (both in and out of universe) because it resurrected Jean Grey. It also usually manifests as a fiery bird.